# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0}\left({\sin{ \sin x}-x(1-x^2)^{\frac23}}\right)x^5?$

Tags: calculus

Can Someone help me?

What is 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left({\sin{ (\sin x)}-x(1-x^2)^{\frac23}}\right)x^-5?$$

Comment: Yes, you can use Taylor expansion at $x=0$ of $\sin(x)$ and $(1+x)^{\alpha}$, it should do it !

Comment: Did you try anything to solve the problem? Is the limit in a certain form you can recognize? As x goes to 0 how is the function behaving like?

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin x = 0 \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin(\sin x) = 0$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (1-x^2)^{2/3} = 1 \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x(1-x^2)^{2/3} = 0$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin(\sin x) - x(1-x^2)^{2/3} = 0-0 = 0$$
ie $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\Big(\sin(\sin x) - x(1-x^2)^{2/3}\Big)x^5 = 0$$

To be honest, although the expression doesn't look simple, the limit is pretty easy as it's just a bunch of zeros. Are you sure that's the right equation? $x^{-5}$ perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

This limit isn't on the indeterminate form and the function is continuous  so the limit is the value at $0$.

Comment: yes.you are right.please look again.I have edited the question..what is the limit now??